# replacing widget at runtime

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Here is the situation. I have a class which is derived from a QListView that adds some convenience functions, a custom widget if you like. I do not want to wrestle with the Designer to use my widget. I simply want to use a plain QlistView in the Designer (as a placeholder) and compile it with pyuic4. At runtime I want to replace that normal QListView with my own version.

How can you do this?

I was hoping something like this in the **init** would do the trick:

```
self.lstView1 = MyListView
```

but it doesn't...

Comment: Please be more specific. "But it doesn't" is not explanatory enough. Is there en error while compiling? Is there an error at runtime? What is the error?

Comment: No errors with the line above. My old plain QListView is still there (visible) and no sign of my custom QListView. I tried some other options too:
self.lstView1 = MyListView(self): here using self (a QDialog) as the parent. The custom listview shows up now but in the wrong place (somewhere in the upper left corner and very small). Then I tried self.lstType = TypeList(self.layoutWidget) where self.layoutWidget is the layout used by the placeholder widget (the plain QListView). It is there again, but still not in the right place. By the way, the old QListview is still there and is never removed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are actually simply replacing the object pointed by lstView1 but not adding it to the widget. That is, when you create you object you simply tell python to point to your new object using lstView1 but the actual UI is using the old pointer since it as already added.

I'm going to assume that you have use py4uci to convert the ui files to python and you set up the gui as:

```
class ExambleUI(QtGUi.QDialog, UI_Example):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       QtGui.QDiialog.__init__(self, parent)
       self.setupUI(self)
       self.lstView1 = MyListView
```

Because setupUi is executing before you change the value of lstView, you are not getting the new widget. You just have to swap the lines:

```
class ExambleUI(QtGUi.QDialog, UI_Example):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       QtGui.QDiialog.__init__(self, parent)
       self.lstView1 = MyListView
       self.setupUI(self)
```

On the other hand I recommend you to follow this [tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq26-pyqtdesigner.html) and create and use you widget in the designer, it is easy and faster.

Comment: It will not work, cause self.lstView1 will be reassigned inside setupUI

Answer (score 1):

Use QLayout replace function:

```
ui->main_layout->replace(oldWidget, newWidget);
```